# Android custom view onDraw

Tags: android, canvas, view, custom-controls

I'm trying to make a control that is a composition of another controls. I've tried many ways but none seems to work... You ask why do I need that? Becaused

1. I've faced the impossibility of creating a TextView with
   different colors of shadow and gradient foreground
2. I want to make
       a volume text and it's going to be presented by this custom controls

   ```
   public class MainMenuItem extends View {
       private MainMenuItemHelper firstLayerItem;
       private MainMenuItemHelper secondLayerItem;

       ...
       @Override
       protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
           super.onDraw(canvas);
           secondLayerItem.draw(canvas);
           firstLayerItem.draw(canvas);
       }
   }


   public class MainMenuItemHelper extends TextView {
       private List<DrawCommand> commands;

       ...
       @Override
       protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
           for (DrawCommand command : commands) {
               command.draw(canvas, getPaint());
               super.onDraw(canvas);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: sure you wanna call `super.onDraw()` in a loop?

Comment: I've tested the MainMenuHelper class in a standalone mode and it works

Comment: `works` doesn't mean it is a good idea :)

Comment: I haven't found another way to implement gradient foreground and shadow layer with different colors

Comment: Have you tried using `<layer-list>` or `<shape>`?

Comment: No I haven't... ;)
Gonna google it right now

Comment: I guess they do not fit the needs

Comment: What do you understand by "gradient foreground"? If you want to draw something on top of your TextView, you should at least call `super.onDraw()` at the very first and then your own `foreground`

Comment: The text of the color should be LinearGradient = gradient foreground
The trick is that I establish null shader at first to draw green shadow and then I clear the shadow layer to draw the text with red gradient set as shader

Comment: I don't get what you try to do but Green and Red aren't very good readable text colors... anyway. Without a screenshot of what you want to achieve, I give up. Sorry

Comment: Could you please then answer the main question?
How do I create a custom control that's composed of another controls.
If I should use View than how do I draw this components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a control that is a composition of another controls

You need at least a Layout like `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` as a View can't contain another View. You need a `ViewGroup` instead.

I don't know where and how you want to place it but the easiest way is to simply make a xml file containing your controls and style them like you would normally do.

A shadow color can be defined by `android:shadowColor` to have a shadow for your text.

Making the text itself being a gradient might be very tricky.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! THANK YOU!!! THANK YOU!!!!
I've killed about 5 hours trying to solve that
and one more time
THANK YOU!!!! THANK YOU!!! THANK YOU!!!!